# Checkbox validation with other field and input field

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am new to Web design.

I have a contact form and I want to validate the form. Current javascript is working well for other fields, but I got stuck with a service field.

Here I want to validate that at least one service is selected and if "Other" option is checked, input field next to it should not be blank.

HTML code (a part of service field) of form is:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contactus" id="contactus" onsubmit="return validate_contactus()" autocomplete="off">

   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Complete new set up of Histopathology Laboratory">Complete new set up of Histopathology Laboratory<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Standardization of Histopath techniques">Standardization of Histopath techniques<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Training of technical staff">Training of technical staff<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Trouble shooting in day to day work">Trouble shooting in day to day work<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Addition of new techniques">Addition of new techniques<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Hands on training">Hands on training<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Seminars & Workshops in Histopathology">Seminars & Workshops in Histopathology<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" value="Preparations of documents for NABL Audits">Preparations of documents for NABL Audits<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service[]" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)"  value="other" >Other

   <input type="text" name="other_text" id="other_text" autocomplete="off" ><br>
```

And javascript I tried with is:

```
var chks = document.contactus.getElementsByName('service[]');
var checkCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
    {
      if (chks[i].checked)
    {
    checkCount++;
    }
    }
    if (checkCount < 1)
    {
      alert("Please select at least One.");
      return false;
    }


    if (document.contactus.getElementById("other").checked && document.contactus.getElementsByName('other_text').value ==="") {
        alert("More Details About Other Service You..... ");
        return false;
    }
```

Also how can I add selected services (**if more than one is checked**) through PHP code? I am emailing this contact form. Currently what I have used is:

```
Contact Person Name :  <?=$_POST['name']?><br><br>
Email :  <?=$_POST['email']?><br><br>
Address : <?=$_POST['address']?><br><br>
Mobile :  <?=$_POST['mobile']?><br><br>
Service Needed :  <?=$_POST['service']?><br><br>
Message : <br><?=$_POST['message']?>
```

Comment: Why did you add the jquery tag if you're not using it? And by the way, *how* is your solution not working?

Comment: i have used php validation too...so even if i didn't check any service, form get proceeded...and page get reloaded with error message "one or more fields are empty.." (I used this error message in php validation)

Comment: what is it really? validation on jquery? on vanilla javascript? in php?

Comment: @Ghost I need javacript. And There are two questions in one. 1) Javascript to validate checkbox for atleast one select and if "other" is checked to validate input field. 2)PHP - how to send email with all services checked (may be two, three or all) ?